# Argument incompatible with parameter?

Tags: c++, windows

I get these errors in my code and I've tried to read the documentation of the errors but I'm having a hard time understanding it.

**The errors:**

[image: Errors]

**This is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include "Source.h"

using namespace std;
DWORD procID;

DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(LPSTR ModuleName)
{

    MODULEENTRY32 module32;
    module32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32); //Module32First will fail if you don't do this
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procID);
    Module32First(hSnap, &module32);
    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) //just a check
        return 0;
    do //iterate through modules
    {
        if (!strcmp(module32.szModule, ModuleName)) //if there is a match
            break;
    } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &module32));
    CloseHandle(hSnap);

    return (DWORD)module32.modBaseAddr;
}
```

Like I said, I have no idea why it does that and would really like to know. If it isn't too much for you guys could someone provide me a solution to this? Thanks.

*NOTE: I am kinda new to this forum so give me feedback on my question if it was easy to understand etc.*

Comment: No screenshots, please.

Comment: What part of "Cannot convert WCHAR[256] to const char *" you do not understand? You cannot convert a pointer to type X to a pointer to type Y (unless Y is a superclass, etc...) C++ does not work this way.

Comment: No screen shots of error messages, and tell us which line it is complaining about ... and provide a [mcve] - there is no definition of `ModuleName` in the code you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling your code with Unicode support. In this mode, the characters are 16 bit entities called `WCHARS`.

Since `strcmp` accepts pointers to `char`, the compiler, correctly, complains that the pointers are incompatible.

There is a function called `wcscmp` which is like `strcmp`, except for `WCHAR`s. Also, there is a function called `_tcscmp` which is supposed to work no matter what your compilation mode is.

You can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx).